# Run some actions at the same time in a makefile

Tags: unix, makefile

I have the following `makefile`.

I would like `step0` to run then I would like all of the `b*.R` scripts to run **at the same time** in `step1`. When `step1` is complete I would like `final` to run.

When I run `make` or `make -j 8` it seems like all of the `b*.R` files still run sequentially. Is this `makefile` set up correctly to run all of the `b*.R` files at the same time? If not what do I need to change.

```
final : step1
    Rscript c.R

step1 : step0
    Rscript b1.R
    Rscript b2.R
    Rscript b3.R
    Rscript b4.R
    Rscript b5.R
    Rscript b6.R

step0 : 
    Rscript a.R
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I run make or make -j 8 it seems like all of the b*.R files still run sequentially.

`-jN` allows parallel execution of **different recipes**, not the individual commands constituting a recipe.

So the makefile should be restructured like this:

```
.PHONY: final b1 b2 b3 b4 b5 b6 step0

final: b1 b2 b3 b4 b5 b6
b1 b2 b3 b4 b5 b6: step0

b1: ;Rscript b1.R
b2: ;Rscript b2.R
b3: ;Rscript b3.R
b4: ;Rscript b4.R
b5: ;Rscript b5.R
b6: ;Rscript b6.R

step0: ;Rscript a.R
```

Comment: so, it looks like the key line here is  `final: b1 b2 b3 b4 b5 b6` which means that all the `b*` targets are required for `final` to run? Also, is `.PHONY` necessary? Also, will the `b` files run at the same time even without `-jN` specified?

Comment: @Alex (1) This is called "prerequisites". Any prerequisite automatically becomes also a target, which is examined and, if necessary, (re-)built **before the original target**. (2) .PHONY says to make that the following targets are not real files, so make never bothers to check if they exist on the disk, but simply executes the corresponding recipes; is this necessary or not depends on your setup. (3) No, without -jN they are executed sequentially from left to right (unless there're extra dependencies between them).

Answer (score 1):

If you want make to handle the parallelism for you, you need to restructure the makefile to have different targets.  For example:

```
step1: b1 b2 b3 b4 b5 b6 
b1: step0
    Rscript b1.R
b2: step0
    Rscript b2.R
...

step0 : 
    Rscript a.R
```

Or, you could let the shell do the parallelism and write:

```
step1: step0
    Rscript b1.R & Rscript b2.R & \
    Rscript b3.R & ... & wait
```

I would recommend the former.

Comment: `step1: step0 b1 b2 b3 b4 b5 b6` This is wrong as `step0` is not guaranteed to end before `b1` is run.