# GNU make targets order when multiple jobs

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have makefile `all: clean $(binary_output_path)/$(target_executable)` which cleans output directory first and the build executable. The problem is when I want to use `-j10`: sometimes it start building and cleaning at the same time, so build fails, obviously.
How can I overcome this and have targets executed in order but on multiple cores?

Comment: Doing `clean` before build is by far the worst of seven deadly sins. If `make` fails, one has to cover his head with ashes and try `make -B`, and if `make -B` also fails, one has to kill himself in shame.

Comment: What can you suggest? I don't really get what's the problem.. :/

Comment: You must remove `clean` from `all`.

Comment: Oh. Yes, but it's just an example tho.

Comment: It's a poor example then. But, speaking in general, if one wants to make sure that some recipe has finished before another, he needs to declare it as a prerequisite (or, sometimes, order-only prerequisite). See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56382640/run-some-actions-at-the-same-time-in-a-makefile/56382943), for example.

Comment: `clean` is a special target in the sense that it does not 'create', but 'destroys'. It impossible to add a dependency on 'destroying something'. So, adding `clean` as a prerequisite to anything is a bad idea and `make` doesn't work like that because order of making prerequisites is not defined when you use `make -j 2`. So, `clean` should only be executed explicitly as `make clean` without specifying any other targets.

Comment: What if I want to invoke it like `make -f Makefile clean all -j10` to rebuild all?

Comment: @KarolisMilieška That would not make any difference. You could do `make clean && make -j10` instead. But I don't understand what's wrong with simply `make -B -j10`.

Comment: @igagis "It impossible to add a dependency on 'destroying something'" - that is not true, you can have perfectly well a dependency involving `clean`. I agree it is not a good idea, but it is possible.  "So, clean should only be executed explicitly as make clean without specifying any other targets" - again, this is not true, and it has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: @MarkGaleck "it has nothing to do with the question" it's a hint to stop adding `clean` as dependency and it IS related to question, essentially it means "don't do what you ask about".

Answer (score 0):

You should add the dependency:

```
$(binary_output_path)/$(target_executable): | clean
```

However, this is not a good idea to use clean like that at all. Just have

```
all: $(binary_output_path)/$(target_executable)
```

`$(binary_output_path)/$(target_executable):` prerequisites

write your recipe here that builds this target

You should focus on writing makefiles in such a way that cleaning is not needed. If you must clean first before building your executable, find out why that is so, and write your commands that build the executable, in such a way that they work regardless of whether you have "cleaned" or not.